# WPF WebBrowser + BingMaps + Bird's eye

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, bing-maps

Is there a way to tell WPF `WebBrowser` to

- navigate into Bing Maps page
- set Bird's eye view of the specific geolocation (latitude,longitude) and;
- make the page appear full-screen

I have taken a look at the Bing Maps page [Create a Custom Map URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx)

but I can't make it work in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Bing Maps API to do this and not the Bing Maps consumer site. If you create a basic webpage you can then host it inside of the WebBrowser control and create an interop to pass commands to the page from C#. For example: http://ayende.com/blog/4366/wpf-webbrowser-and-javascript-interaction

Here is a sample web page that could be used as a starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Map with birds eye view</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = null;

      function getMap()
      {
         map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key', center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.6215, -122.349329), mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye, zoom: 18});
      }

    function setView(latitude, longitude, zoom){
        map.setView({center:new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latutude, longitude), zoom: zoom});
    }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="getMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```